# LearnDash lesson_complete Shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I'm using LearnDash for WordPress and am trying to write a custom shortcode.
I need a shortcode that will display specific text when a Lesson is Complete.

I'm not great (at all!) with WordPress functions or writing shortcodes, but I really need this!

I'd like to be able to wrap shortcodes around some text and only display the text if the current lesson is complete.
[lesson_complete] TEXT HERE [/lesson_complete]

LearnDash provided some code for when the lesson is complete, but I'm not sure how I would use it to write the shortcode.

```
add_action("learndash_lesson_completed", function($data) {
    //Called when lesson is completed
}, 5, 1);
```

I've tried this, but I'm sure I'm way off...

```
//Create a shortcode for Lesson Complete
function is_lesson_complete ($content = null){
    $lessonDone = 0;
    add_action("learndash_lesson_completed", function($data) {
        $lessonDone = 1;
    }, 5, 1);
    if ( $lessonDone == 1 ){

        return $content;
    } else {

        return "";
    }
}
    //add a shortcode which calls the above function
    add_shortcode('lesson_complete', 'is_lesson_complete' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's very interesting question,Let's divide this problem into two small parts.

First is
**how to create proper custom shortcode in wordpress** ?

Second is **How to check if course is complete call function that will display our desire text in our current scenario.**

Good News! you're going good you just need to do few things clean.

For LearnDash -

If Course has been completed. it will display the function.

you just have to create a function like this and return whatever you want to return.

but before using learnDash course complete code. 
here you go

[**learn how to make a proper shortcode in wordpress**](https://pagely.com/blog/creating-custom-shortcodes/).

```
add_action("learndash_course_completed", function($data) {
//Called when course is completed
}, 5, 1);
```

**[Reference link](https://www.learndash.com/support/docs/developers/hooks-and-filters/)**

I hope this will help you :) Happy Coding.

Comment: I'm looking to only call it on specific lessons, not all of them. Would there be a way to have it show up only on certain lessons?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, we can I believe. If there is no option we can create custom by editing learn course api.

Comment: Still not sure where I'm going...  Do I add the "add_action" code to my function.php file?  How do I get it to only show specific lessons?

Comment: Thanks Muhammad!  I appreciate your help!